# The Macmillan's Theorem (Shiryaev Probability-1, Third Edition, page 51)

Tags: probability

[image: The pic]

My question is:
(1) why $p(w) = exp \{ - \sum v_k \log p_k \} $? Specifically, I don't understand why there is a "-" prior to the sum.

(2) Please correct my proof:

$p(w) = exp \{ \sum v_k \log p_k \} \le exp \{ \sum (np_k + \epsilon_1 n) \log p_k \}$

right side = $exp \{ n ( \sum p_k \log p_k + \epsilon_1 \sum \log p_k) \}$
= $exp \{ -n ( \sum -p_k \log p_k - \epsilon_1 \sum \log p_k) \}$
= $exp \{ -n ( H - \epsilon_1 \sum \log p_k) \}$

because $\epsilon_1 \le \epsilon / \{ -2 \sum \log p_k \}$
So the right side  $\le exp \{ -n ( H - \frac{ \epsilon }{-2}) \}$
= $exp \{ -n ( H + \frac{ \epsilon }{2} ) \}$

But the answer is $exp \{ -n ( H - \frac{ \epsilon }{2} ) \}$

So please help me correct my proof. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You've probably figure out by now that it is a typical typo. As you pointed out,

$$
p(\omega):=\prod_k p_k^{\nu_k(\omega)}=\exp{\sum_k \nu_k\log p_k}.
$$

The thing to remember is $\log p_k\le0$.

Then since $np_k-\epsilon_1 n<\nu_k$, the book's proof follows if you systematically correct the typo in the sign:
$$
\exp{\sum_k \nu_k\log p_k}<\exp{\left[n\sum_k p_k\log p_k-\epsilon_1 n\sum_k \log p_k\right]}\\
\le \exp{\left[-nH +\epsilon_1 n\sum_k -\log p_k\right]}\\
\le \exp{\left[-nH +\epsilon n\frac{\sum_k -\log p_k}{2\sum_k -\log p_k}\right]},\\
$$
etc.